# jquery mobile splitview plugin, transition from a non-split page to a split page

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

I´m using jquery mobile for an iPad app, and I wanted to have the typical splitview layout so I used the splitview plugin which is working fine until now, but I would still have some minor questions:

- Can my first page be a normal page, meaning non-split and then when for example I click on a button go to the second page which would be split?
- How do I do to enlarge the left panel if I find it a bit narrow?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did u got any solution ? Even i am looking for the same.

Try using the simplesplitview http://simplesplitview.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. 
I am able to workaround this by providing rel="external" on the link in my navigation menu. This however reloads the entire page, and the ajax effect is gone.

```
            <li><a href='somepage' rel="external">Some Text</a></li>
```

I will be spending some time on it this weekend to get it working through ajax, will let you know if I find a solution.